# Writing a proper (and simple) auth/login class in PHP

Tags: php, security

How to write and design a simple (but still proper and secure) login class for PHP?

Currently I'm checking whether there is a login request (user entered data into login form) or the session is already existent and contains `$_SESSION['authenticated'] == TRUE;`. If both checks failed the user is not (properly) logged in. In code:

```
class Auth {
    private function __construct() {
        // new login
        if(isset($_POST['login'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) && validCSRFToken()) {
            $user = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            if(($row = querySingle('
               SELECT `id`, `password`
               FROM `users` u
               WHERE `nick` = "?"',
               $user)))
               // Crypt::hash checks the salted password
               && Crypt::hash($password, $row['password'])) {
                // credential change (guest -> user) regenerate session id
                session_regenerate_id(TRUE);

                $_SESSION['authenticated'] = TRUE;
                $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['id'];
                $_SESSION['user'] = $user;

                // prevent 'your browser has to re-send some data to display this page'
                redirect($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            } else {
                $this->logout();
                throw new AuthException('login failed. wrong user/password');
            }
        } else if($_SESSION['authenticated'] && $_SESSION['userid'] > 0 && !empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
            // user already logged in, nothing to see here, move on
        } else {
                    // not logged in!
                    throw new AuthException('not logged in. please login');
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->authenticated = FALSE;
        $this->user = '';
        $this->userid = 0;

        $this->session->destroy();
        $this->session->regenerate_id(TRUE);
    }
}
```

An object of the `Auth` class has to be created on every page that requires authentication from users:

```
try {
  $auth = new Auth();

  /*
   * rest of the page
   */

} catch(AuthException $ex) {
  // something went wrong during login
  displayError();
  displayLoginForm();
  exit; // halt further execution of script
}
```

Is this the right way to do it? Do you see anything (seriously) flawed with this approach? Can users impersonate other users? Users getting logged out randomly? Users getting logged out by malicious attackers? (although CSRF checks are in place). I'm afraid, I might be missing something obvious.

Any improvements apreciated, thanks!

(Please don't suggest using a PHP framework like CodeIgniter, Zend Framework, Kohana, etc.)

Comment: Have you tried using oAuth?

Comment: Seems perfectly valid to me. Is there a real question?

Comment: Tip: Don't use exceptions to signal a standard case (auth failed), better have a auth state you can ask for (authenticated, unauthenticated).

Comment: @hakre: I'm afraid some page forgets to check the auth state … thus the exception, that way it is garuanteed to abort the script

Comment: @nkittl: If that's the case, you should implement authentication on another layer probably. Just saying, you can use exceptions to gain something like a signal, however, keep in mind that it's not the right tool for the job. Might give you more problems than solutions in the end. Better check why some scripts are not checking authentication and think about twice.

Comment: I think you should consider checking for valid user in database even if you have valid session data. I had a very stupid problem once when deleted user was still "logged in" after he was deleted and one badly written query screwed our database a little.

Comment: Forgot one more thing: usually you should check for $_POST variables after you check if user is already logged in($_SESSION), as it is very strange for a user to make double log in (and succesfull $_SESSION checks should be much more often, so making it first check will make your application slightly faster(as next checks will not be triggered), not that it matters, but still more logical). Just swap checks for $_SESSION and $_POST in your main IF tree.

Answer (score 4):

At the first look, no big hole shines through. Some points that can be considered, on the order of appearance:

1. Instead of directly using the `$_POST`, you can take these as parameters, thus making it look like more of an API. Example usage: when you want to directly log in people who have just  registered. You will not be tied to some particular `$_POST` parameters.
2. `Crypt::hash ...`: Not seeing the interior of this, one can't comment much but from the looks, the salt seems constant, unless you are querying the users table again inside this. A different (and preferably with a length matching the password) salt for each user is generally the way to go in security-conscious developer environments.
3. Similar to the #1, you can use a wrapper class for `$_SESSION` usage.
4. `else if($_SESSION['authenticated'] && $_SESSION['userid'] > 0 && !empty($_SESSION['user']))`: Instead of directly querying the `$_SESSION`, you can make another function like `$this->isLoggedIn()`, so you'd be more resistant to future session and log in changes (along with some other benefits).
5. `redirect($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` Relying on a `$_SERVER` variable always looked insecure and unstable to me. You can use some checks here or use some of your internal navigation variables instead, in case you don't want to make it completely generic in this way.

Comment: `Crypt::hash` uses a randomly generated user-unique salt (let's assume the usage of `crypt`). Wrapper class for session seems overhead to me, but was actually in use. 4) good point. 5) if the server was compromised then I've lost already, imo. the redirect call should probably be wrapped in a `refresh()`

Comment: But how `Crypt::hash` knows the specific salt for the user in question? It can generate random salts during registration, but what about log-in time, i.e. checking that salt?

Comment: it's stored as part of the password. [`crypt`](http://php.net/crypt) does the same thing

Comment: Ok, sorry for asking about something obvious :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd also add validation of 'login', 'username' and 'password' before running the query.